# Removing all Documents from Mongo Collection under Meteor

Tags: meteor

The browser console shows the records the collection has, but when I try `Tasks.remove({});` in the browser console I get some error:

> errorClass {error: 403, reason: "Not permitted. Untrusted code may only remove documents by ID.", details: undefined, message: "Not permitted. Untrusted code may only remove documents by ID. [403]", errorType: "Meteor.Error"}

Any idea how to remove all the documents from the collection including the _id(s)? Thanks

```js
Meteor.subscribe('tasks');

Meteor.publish('tasks', function(){
  return Tasks.find();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only remove multiple documents at once on the server as [documented on the Meteor site](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/remove).

So to clear the collection you'll need to do this in server code, and create a method if you need to call this from the client.